# Match Failure Issue OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm getting a match failure for my OCaml code and I have no idea what the issue might be. I attempted having one case only and going from there to figure out where the issue comes up but the error I receive is :

```
Exception: Match_failure ("hw2.ml", 49, 0).
```

Code :

```
let rec compileStack(il : instr list) (st : float list) =
 match (il,st) with
 [],[_] -> List.hd st
 |((Push f)::t),[_] -> compileStack t (f::st)
 |(Swap)::t, h2::h1::st   -> compileStack t (h2::h1::st)
 |(Calculate op)::t, h1::h2::st ->
  match op with
    Plus -> compileStack t (h2+.h1::st)
  | Minus -> compileStack t (h2-.h1::st)
  | Times -> compileStack t (h2*.h1::st)
  | Divide -> compileStack t (h2/.h1::st)  ;;                               

let execute (li : instr list) : float =
  let stack = [] in
  compileStack li stack;;
```

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated, been stuck on this for 2 hours now.

Comment: What's your input data for the failing test? By the way, pattern-matching on (il, st) is not exhaustive: you missed a bunch of cases. This seems to be your problem.

Answer (score 2):

When compiling pay attention to the compiler's output. If it says something like

```
Warning ...: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
```

then it usually means you skipped some cases. By the way, the compiler provides an example of missed cases.

Considering your problem, I'd separate different jobs into different functions -- that will let you handle those cases easier; also don't forget about stack underflows, which happen when there is not enough data in the stack to perform swaps or binary arithmetic operations. See the example below.

```
(* just type aliases for convenience *)
type stack = float list
type binop = float -> float -> float

(* helper function to prevent nested pattern matching below *)
let denote_operation (op : oper) : binop =
  match op with
    | Plus   -> ( +. )
    | Minus  -> ( -. )
    | Times  -> ( *. )
    | Divide -> ( /. )

(* This function executes only 1 instruction and 
   returns 'stack option', which may signal stack underflow *)
let execute_instruction (i : instr) (st : stack) : stack option =
  match i with
    | Push f -> Some (f :: st)
    | Swap ->
       (match st with
          | y :: x :: st' -> Some (x :: y :: st')
          | _ -> None)
    | Calculate op ->
       (match st with
          | y :: x :: st' -> Some ((denote_operation op x y) :: st')
          | _ -> None)

(* this function deals with a bunch of instructions *)
let rec execute_program (il : instr list) (st : stack) : stack option =
  match il with
    | [] -> Some st
    | i :: il' ->
       match (execute_instruction i st) with
         | None -> None
         | Some st' -> execute_program il' st'
```